# Write decoded message from one channel to another channel cause IllegalBufferAccessException Exception

Tags: exception, proxy, netty

I am new to netty. I change the example of HexDumpProxy by adding http codec handler to write the decoded http message from the sever channel to the backend client channel and when the client get the http response it will decode the message  and write the response  message back to the inboundChannel (in the messageReceived event). But this always cause io.netty.buffer.IllegalBufferAccessException Exception. I would be very grateful for your any help. Thanks for your time.

io.netty.buffer.IllegalBufferAccessException
    at io.netty.buffer.AbstractReferenceCountedByteBuf.release(AbstractReferenceCountedByteBuf.java:114)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.http.DefaultFullHttpRequest.release(DefaultFullHttpRequest.java:69)
    at io.netty.buffer.BufUtil.release(BufUtil.java:76)
    at io.netty.channel.ChannelHandlerUtil.handleInboundBufferUpdated(ChannelHandlerUtil.java:62)
    at io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundMessageHandlerAdapter.inboundBufferUpdated(ChannelInboundMessageHandlerAdapter.java:100)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelHandlerContext.invokeInboundBufferUpdated(DefaultChannelHandlerContext.java:1031)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelHandlerContext.fireInboundBufferUpdated0(DefaultChannelHandlerContext.java:998)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelHandlerContext.fireInboundBufferUpdated(DefaultChannelHandlerContext.java:978)
    at io.netty.channel.ChannelHandlerUtil.handleInboundBufferUpdated(ChannelHandlerUtil.java:69)
    at io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundMessageHandlerAdapter.inboundBufferUpdated(ChannelInboundMessageHandlerAdapter.java:100)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelHandlerContext.invokeInboundBufferUpdated(DefaultChannelHandlerContext.java:1031)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelHandlerContext.fireInboundBufferUpdated0(DefaultChannelHandlerContext.java:998)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelHandlerContext.fireInboundBufferUpdated(DefaultChannelHandlerContext.java:978)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ReplayingDecoder.callDecode(ReplayingDecoder.java:441)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.inboundBufferUpdated(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:69)
    at io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundByteHandlerAdapter.inboundBufferUpdated(ChannelInboundByteHandlerAdapter.java:46)
    at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.inboundBufferUpdated(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:175)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelHandlerContext.invokeInboundBufferUpdated(DefaultChannelHandlerContext.java:1031)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelHandlerContext.fireInboundBufferUpdated0(DefaultChannelHandlerContext.java:998)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelHandlerContext.fireInboundBufferUpdated(DefaultChannelHandlerContext.java:978)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireInboundBufferUpdated(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:828)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:118)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:429)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:392)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:322)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:114)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Answer (score 0):

The API has changed since this release.. Please use the latest version which is 4.0.0.CR9.